# Артиллерия, пр(е/и)крой?

Tags: орфография

*Артиллерия прекрой* (в значении словосочетания, предполагается помощь артиллерии на протяжении всего боя). Или же все таки: *Артиллерия прикрой* (но здесь уже значение совсем иное предполагается кратковременная помощь)?
Правильно ли я понимаю написание, или же в любом случае, второе слово в этом словосочетании пишется с приставкой *при*-? Тогда почему?

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае предполагается, скорее всего, значение слова "перекрой" - перекрыть дорогу, отрезать путь. Во втором прикрой - неполное действие - поэтому приставка "при".

Answer (score 1):

Однозначно! Прикрой - неполнота действия.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае это обращение (приказ, просьба). То есть, должна стоять еще и запятая. "Артиллерия, прикрой" (ну или "Артиллерия! Прикрой!"). Выражается кратковременность действия.

Answer (score 0):

Только один вариант: прикрой. В любом из данных примеров. Остальное - ошибка!

Answer (score 0):

Артиллерия может *прикрывать* пехоту на протяжении всего, *полного* боя. Неполнота действия (приставка "при") здесь относится не ко времени, а к качеству самого действия: артиллерия не может *полностью оградить* (ЗАкрыть, ЗАгородить) пехоту от действий противника; но только ПРИкрыть, поддержать.

Answer (score 0):

Прикрыть. Во всех значениях. Кстати, не вижу здесь каких-то особо различающихся значений. 
Что на протяжении боя, что разово, артиллерия (и не только она) пр**и**крывает, никак не пр**е**крывает.

Давайте от печки. У "при-" есть как минимум два значения, в школе их обычно обозначают как неполнота действия и сближение. Так вот, "неполнота действия" очень часто является чито грамматической, в реалиях действие является вполне законченным. Ну что, простите "неполного" в "призадуматься", "приревновать", "приукрасить(ся)"?! Нечто похожее мы можем наблюдать и в "прикрыть". Но скорее всего тут другое значение - сближать. Исходное значение - накрыть: "прикрой меня пледом". Перенесение на военные действия идет не по типу действия, а по его назначению - оградить. не от холода, понятно, но от огня противника.

В любом случае ни одно из значение для "пре" - не годится. Высшую степень качества исключаем сразу за очевидной невозможностью, а близкое к "пере-" по смыслу: "прекрыть" (перекрыть) можно в лучшем случае вражий огонь, но никак не того, кого от него прикрывают.